# can I have a button next to the select option? if can't, can I put the button outside and connect with the option in the select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want is when you select and there are multiple options showing with two buttons. When the button is clicked, I want to take the option value,( which might be id) and do some functions. 
Is it possible?
If I put buttons outside next to each option, how can I connect with the option in the multiple select?

[image]

Comment: Can I use jQuery ? or pure JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example using jQuery

```
<select id="choice" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option value="three">three</option>
</select>

<button type="button">one</button>
<button type="button">two</button>
<button type="button">three</button>

<script>
$('button').click(function() {
  var val = $(this).text(); // one, two, three
  $("#choice option[value='" + val + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
</script>
```

[Online Verification](https://jsfiddle.net/nf7m80e6/1/)